# RSASSA-PSS p1v2.1 (rfc 4056) signing

Tags: rsa, signature

I'm signing mails with the RSASSA-PSS (p1v2.1) certificate. When I click Details, it shows "Signature Algorithm: RSASSA-PSS".
openssl x509 -text shows

```
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha256
     Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
```

certutil -dump shows:

```
1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 RSASSA-PSS
```

Now, whem I send my signed emails and click on Details in outlook, it shows "Signature Algorithm: RSA (2048)"

I'm using bouncycastle for signing and when I use "SHA256WithRSAEncryption" it works fine, but when I'm using "SHA256WithRSAAndMGF1" Signature, Outlook tells me "The digital signature on this item is Invalid or Not Trusted." and when I click details, I see "Signature Algorithm: RSA (2048)".
Is p#1v2.1 still not supported by outlook/microsoft or am I just crazy?

Comment: Why a program does not accept a signature format is off-topic here; I'm thus thinking of migrating to [security-SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). That said, one possibility worth checking would be that the hash algorithm used in MGF1 is not the same on both sides: it's not specified by SHA256WithRSAAndMGF1. I have been hit (in encryption, not signature) by Java libraries where MGF1 is by default understood to use SHA-1 even when the algorithm's name mentions SHA-256, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33572909/903600).

Comment: Note: as of 2020 this apparently wasn't supported, see the conversation [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sending-signed-and-encrypted-messages-with-outlook/5056661c-a099-4819-8947-55893d81d37d) with an (initially helpful) Jenifer from Microsoft trying to fill the gaps, but getting wrong footed by her own engineers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is p#1v2.1 still not supported by outlook/microsoft or am I just crazy?

PSS seems still not introduced to Microsoft, please see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sending-signed-and-encrypted-messages-with-outlook/5056661c-a099-4819-8947-55893d81d37d). It's a long discussion, but in the end it seems that you cannot select PSS as a signature scheme when sending, I presume that also means that PSS signatures are not accepted.

RSA-OAEP based encryption is generally supported earlier than PSS. There are padding oracle attacks against the PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption scheme. The PKCS#1 v1.5 signature scheme is still considered secure, so there is much less need for upgrading it.